# Static noise from headphones

Tags: audio, noise

I have a static noise coming from my headphones when no music/noise is being played on the computer (running Windows 7).

I have tested with 3 pairs of headphones using Realtek High Definition Audio 6.0.1.6196. When there is a noise output, the fuzziness stops.

What could be causing it?

Comment: there is a noise output, the fuzziness stops - please elaborate, you **measured** stops or just don't hear low-level pickups?

Comment: Ok, so when there is any audio output from the OS, the noise disappears. A good test is the `test` under Advanced in Headphone Properties - clicking this provides half a second of silence, then the example noise is played completely clear, then once its finished the "fuzziness" begins again

Comment: You can try to test with another (preferable Hi-Fi level) sound-card. Your card or badly designed or (more probably) poorly assembled

Answer (score 5):

It could be leakage of electrical noise - the cables behave as an antenna and pick pick up stray electromagnetic signals.I've had electrical noise leak into a pair of headphones plugged into a desktop (in my case, a dell inspiron 530). Its less static, than something that sounds vaguely like the sound you get when a handphone gets a text near speakers

There's not much you can do about it, except maybe somehow shield the cables in question.

Comment: In the case of noise, captured in a short antenna with the such level of the signal intensity of the electromagnetic field would be shown a much better and earlier - hair loss and other signs of the impact of power HF-waves

Comment: Well, it does sound similar to what a induction coil mic picks up from the average piece of electronics.In addition, its a VERY short distance between the source, and whatever is picking up. Feel free to post a scientifically accurate, presumably cited answer.

Comment: I feel free to ignore this request - I don't want to answer, I only, with all due respect, show you some your mistakes... See difference?!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need a ferrite choke(those strange lumps you find on random cables). Google it. The removable ones are hard to find, but they do exist.

Comment: can you add a link or two explaining how this solution should help?